# Install4j Update Installation context.isUpdateInstallation always returns false

Tags: windows, install4j

During my update installation, i have show an additional screen. I have added a new screen with conditional expression as **context.isUpdateInstallation()**. **However this is always returning false and hence not showing this screen even during update installation as well**. I have tried using context.getBooleanVariable("sys.confirmedUpdateInstallation") which is also not helping me. So basically i could not determine the installation type to be update installation in my installer.

*Note: The update installation is integrated with launcher where launcher downloads latest update and auto launches the update installer while launching the application.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`context.isUpdateInstallation()` only returns true if the currently selected installation directory (returned by `context.getInstallationDirectory()`) contains an installation with the same application ID (configured on Installer->Update Options").

Comment: I used App name and version for app Id which was a mistake. Once I removed version from the application Id, context.isUpdateInstallation was working fine. Thanks!!